# RegEx Issue - Can't figure out why one of the condition is matching

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Good Day

Explanation of what I'm trying to do:

I have a component with checkboxes and names:

[x] foo 
[ ] bar 
[ ] orange

If I select foo, I only want to match records that contain "foo" not "foo (bar)" or any other arrangement. The RegEx I built to do this is:

(?<=(\s|^))(${dropdownList.join('|')})(?=(\s|$))\im

The dropdownList.join will only contain the checked items, so using the list above you'll get:

(?<=(\s|^))(foo)(?=(\s|$))\im

Now, I'm using this to iterate over a table and look at a value, then disable the row if it doesn't match.  In the table I can have values of foo or foo (bar), what I can't figure out is why foo (bar) is matching when I run a search for foo.

0 is the return value of "foo".search(regex), which should be -1, if I don't have "foo", so "foo (bar)" should be -1.

I tested this in https://regex101.com/, and it seems to work, fine when I do it there.

String Value
foo
Search Term
/(?<=(\s|^))(foo)(?=(\s|$))/im
0

String Value
foo (bar)
Search Term
/(?<=(\s|^))(foo)(?=(\s|$))/im
0 (Shouldn't this be -1)

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Here is the function I'm using for the search, I've added updated Regex:

```js
public _validateValues(): Promise < any > {
  return new Promise((r) => {
    const dropdownList = [];
    _.forEach(this.columnSearchHistory, (searchItem: TableSearchHistory) => {
      if (searchItem.type === 'dropdown') {
        dropdownList.push(this.escapeRegExp(searchItem.value?.toString().trim() ?? ''));
      }
    });

    let searchTerm;
    if (dropdownList.length) {
      searchTerm = new RegExp(`(^)(${dropdownList.join('|')})($)`, 'im');
    }

    _.forEach(this.headerList, (row) => {
      row.filtered = false;
    })

    this.activateAllRows();

    _.forEach(this.columnSearchHistory, (searchItem: TableSearchHistory) => {
      this.headerList[searchItem.headerIndex].filtered = true;

      if (searchItem.value && searchItem.type !== 'dropdown') {
        searchTerm = new RegExp(this.escapeRegExp(searchItem.value ? .toString().trim()), 'i');
      } else if (searchItem.type === 'dropdown') {
        searchTerm = new RegExp(`(^)(${dropdownList.join('|')})($)`, 'im');

        console.log('Search Term');
        console.log(searchTerm);
      }

      if (searchItem.type === 'number') {
        if (searchItem.min === null) {
          searchItem.min = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }

        if (searchItem.max === null) {
          searchItem.max = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        }
      }

      if (searchItem.type === 'date') {
        if (searchItem.min === null) {
          searchItem.min = new Date('1926');
        }

        if (searchItem.max === null) {
          searchItem.max = new Date(Date.now());
        }
      }

      _.forEach(this.data, (row, rowIdx) => {

        let value = row[this.headerList[searchItem.index].key];

        if (searchItem.type === 'number') {

          if (!value && value !== 0) {
            row.active = false;
          }

          if (!value && value !== 0) {
            value = 0;
          }

          const numericValue = Number(value.toString().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));

          const max = Number(searchItem.max);
          const min = Number(searchItem.min);

          if (numericValue < min || numericValue > max) {

            row.active = false;
          }
        } else if (searchItem.type === 'date') {
          if (!value) {
            row.active = false;
          }

          if (!value) {
            value = new Date();
          } else {
            value = new Date(value);
          }

          const max = new Date(searchItem.max);
          const min = new Date(searchItem.min);

          if (value < min || value > max) {
            row.active = false;
          }
        } else {
          const stringValue = value ? value : '';

          if (stringValue.toString().trim().search(searchTerm) === -1) {
            row.active = false;
          }
        }
      })
    })

    this.range = {
      low: null,
      high: null,
      search: ''
    };

    r(this.data);
  })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very confusing. It would be easier if you explained what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: Simple, why if I run the search for foo, is foo (bar) getting matched?  Shouldn't foo (bar) get -1 when I run the .search()?

Comment: Without looking too much into this, you're using an array join which means it's only going to match 'foo' OR 'bar' OR 'orange'. If you want to match 'foo' AND 'bar' then this isn't the right approach.

Comment: I updated the post, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: It is much clearer of what you're trying to do; but, when I copy/pasted your regex I get an error with the regex site you suggested.

Comment: Also, if I'm understanding you correctly, you have a list of checkboxes:
[ ] word_one
[ ] word_two
[ ] word_three

Are you wanting it so that when you check one that only strings with the checked words are matched and the non-checked rows are omitted?

Comment: Make sure you switch it over to JavaScript it and remove the \im I added, it will be already be on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help here.

First, your RegExp is not correct in its current form. The ${ code } section will be interpreted literally. You need to declare your Regex as:

```
const rx = new RegExp("(?<=(\s|^))("+dropdownList.join('|')+")(?=(\s|$))","i");
```

I've removed the m flag. This is for a multiline string which I don't believe we have here.

Second, if you try and match the string 'foo' it will match any string containing it.

- foo
- foo (bar)
- foo foo foo
- foo notfoo

All these will match as they contain the string 'foo'.

You may want to do a whole string match so try this:

```
const rx = new RegExp("^"+dropdownList.join("|")+"$","i");
```

This is simply:

```
^ - the start of the string
foo|bar|orange - whatever your selected options are
$ - the end of the string.
```

```js
const dropdownList = ['foo'];

//let rx = new RegExp("^" + dropdownList.join("|") + "$");
let rx = new RegExp(`^${dropdownList.join('|')}$`, 'im');

console.log(rx.test("foo"));
// true

console.log(rx.test("foo (bar)"));
// false
```

Comment: `(^)(${dropdownList.join('|')})($)`  Is actually working!  What I can't figure out is why the RegEx works fine in the test site, but not in my code.

The `` denotes that ${} will be expanded, so it will give the proper output when it's evaluated, but thanks for that suggestion;.

The idea is if I pick foo and bar, then only "foo" and "bar" are matched, but not "foo (bar)". 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your actual code? 
I would define this as above in my example. You don't need to put everything in ( )'s either. This is for capturing to $1 $2 $3 variables etc

If happy please vote my answer ;)

Comment: I added the function into my post, you can see the RegEx you provided which previously housed my old RegEx.   What that function is doing, is looping over a bunch of data, and setting an "active" flag.

Comment: I've added a snippet to test the regex (but removed unnecessary brackets). The regex works, so this is not your problem.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the lack of a response, forgot about this post.  For now the Regex is working fine, the modified on, so I'm going to keep on using it.  Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I was thinking:

```
<div class="example flex_column"></div>

// your strings which you may be filtering...
const possible_strings = [
  'foo is the bar',
  'foo is all',
  'bar foo',
  'orange this is orange',
  'fooing'
];

// utility functions for readability
const createElement = (type) => document.createElement(type);
const qs = (el) => document.querySelector(el);
const qsAll = (el) => document.querySelectorAll(el);

// creates the options you see based on words
const makeOption = (word) => {
  const $label = createElement('label');
  const $span = createElement('span');
  $span.textContent = word;
  const $input = createElement('input');
  $input.type = 'checkbox';
  $input.name = 'words';
  $label.append($span, $input);
  
  return $label;
}


// updates Map (hashmap) based on options selected
const getSentences = ($el, hash_map) => {
    const $input = $el.querySelector('input');
    $input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
         const $label = e.target.closest('label');
         const word_checked = $label.querySelector('span').innerText;
         if ($label.querySelector('input').checked) hash_map.set(word_checked, 1);
         else hash_map.set(word_checked, 0);
    
         const words = [...hash_map.keys() ];
         const words_wanted = words.filter((word) => hash_map.get(word));
         const words_not_wanted = words.filter((word) => !hash_map.get(word));
    
         let keepers = possible_strings.filter((sentence) => {
             return sentence.match(new RegExp(`(^|\\s)(${words_wanted.join('|')})($|\\s)`))
         });
    
         keepers = keepers.filter((sentence) => {
              return !sentence.match(new RegExp(`(^|\\s)(${words_not_wanted.join('|')})($|\\s)`))
         })
         console.log(keepers);
     });
  
  return $el;
}

const example = () => {
  // the options you have
  const words = ['foo', 'bar', 'orange'];
  const hash_map = new Map();
  words.forEach((word) => hash_map.set(word, 0));
  const $example = qs('.example');
  $example.append(
    ...words.map((word) => getSentences(makeOption(word), hash_map)));
}

example();

.flex_column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/aq8o25nr/2

How does it work? It creates options based on "words". I create a hashmap of all the words. ie:

Map {
'foo': 0,
'bar': 0,
'orange': 0
}

each time you click an option it changes 0 to 1. (identifying the words you want whereas 0 identfies the words you dont want).

That way we just regex the senteces first for the words you want (1s) then we regex that result with words you dont want (the 0s). Thus giving you the matches of checked but omitting the unchecked options. I made it dynamically so you can change the array size of words or change sentences.